Wifi deteriorates over time; cronjob to restart network manager
I have an issue with my Ubuntu machine and WIFI, which apparently is difficult to resolve. Turning off and on the wifi fixes it (temporarily). When trying to connect from outside and the speed is very low, I can run
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

and the connection improves drastically. I was thinking about automatizing this -- perhaps I could set this up as a cronjob every midnight?
Unfortunately, as I understand it, this would require storing my root password in plain text, which I rather not do. Is there perhaps another approach I could take (absent of solving the core issue, which appears impossible)?

No, you should store the Cron job in root's crontab, which is done with:
sudo crontab -e

And then the command you add to restart the service at 00:13 is:
13 0 * * * systemctl restart NetworkManager

